# ASP.NET FormView OnItemInserting and OnItemInserted

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, formview

My code is executing the OnItemInserting function but not the OnItemInserted.  Have I declared the Inserted function correctly?

aspx

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserting="Insert" OnItemInserted="Inserted">
```

vb

```
Protected Sub Insert(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserting
' Works
End Sub


Protected Sub Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserted
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") ' Never gets here
End Sub
```

The code never enters the Inserted function and just refreshes the form after executing the Insert

Comment: Everything I find suggests this code should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemInserted` event will be raised only if FormView is data-bound and the data-source handles the insert (and subsequently call backs the control after insert).

I suspect that you have not bound your form-view to any data source control (such as SqlDataSource). In case, you are planning to handle inserting into the data-store by writing custom code then you should do that part in `ItemInserting` event itself.